# openssl -aes-128-ecb encryption doesn't match python Crypto.Cipher AES encryption

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, cryptography

I am trying to encrypt the string of 16 bytes "Attack at dawn!!" using AES-128 with the password "yellow submarine".

In python :

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64encode

plaintext = 'Attack at dawn!!'
obj = AES.new("yellow submarine", AES.MODE_ECB)
ciphertext = obj.encrypt(plaintext)

print(b64encode(ciphertext).decode())
```

This gives the ciphertext as 'kBKTLPWpU7Dpf/TiGo6p3w=='

Now using openssl in terminal. plain.txt is a text file containing the string 'Attack at dawn!!':

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -nopad -pass pass:"yellow submarine" -in plain.txt -out cipher.txt -a
```

This returns 'X+fHjd97VRZLbH+BCgu6Xw==' as the ciphertext.

Why are they not the same?

I've tried reading documentation or examples, but haven't found anything useful on the internet. I've tried changing the options in the openssl command. I don't know how else to approach this problem.

Comment: Why should they be the same? openssl uses a proprietary key derivation algorithm to convert a password to a key and IV, and pycrypto does something else. If you use the `-P` option you can see what the derived key and IV are. Use those in your pycrypto code.

Comment: Naively, I was thinking that the password and the key were the same thing. I clearly didn't read the manual closely enough, because as you say `-P` will spit out the actual key (and the IV if the mode uses one). There is also `-K` which allows a key to be used directly.

Comment: @JamesKPolk thank you! that sorted out my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, encrypting using AES from Crypto.Cipher takes a key (string of 16 bytes) and a plaintext (16 bytes) and outputs a ciphertext (16 bytes).

To achieve the same with OpenSSL you need to first disable salting and padding with `-nosalt` and `-nopad` to ensure it takes 16 byte inputs and returns 16 byte outputs. Supplying a password results in OpenSSL deriving its own key. To override this, use the `-K` option (where the key needs to be given in hex). Alternatively, inputting a password and specifying `-p` will make OpenSSL spit out the key that it uses.

- Using the key 'yellow submarine':

python

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64encode

plaintext = 'Attack at dawn!!'
obj = AES.new("yellow submarine", AES.MODE_ECB)
ciphertext = obj.encrypt(plaintext)

print(b64encode(ciphertext).decode())
```

openssl

```
enc -aes-128-ecb openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -nopad -K 79656c6c6f77207375626d6172696e65 -in plain.txt -out cipher.txt -a
```

This gives 'kBKTLPWpU7Dpf/TiGo6p3w==' for both methods.

- Using the OpenSSL password 'yellow submarine':

  openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -nopad -p -pass pass:"yellow submarine" -in plain.txt -out cipher.txt -a

This outputs the key as 'A35EC217E15C1DD258201A184814897C'. To use this with Crypto.Cipher, we first need to convert it to hex.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64encode

hex_key = 'A35EC217E15C1DD258201A184814897C'
key = bytes.fromhex(hex_key)

plaintext = 'Attack at dawn!!'
obj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
ciphertext = obj.encrypt(plaintext)

print(b64encode(ciphertext).decode())
```

This gives 'X+fHjd97VRZLbH+BCgu6Xw==' for both methods.

- To answer the final question: you should have read the manual for OpenSSL enc more closely, and spotted the `-p`, `-P` and `-k` options.